# Task cancellation best practices

Tags: c#, .net, task, task-parallel-library

Lets say I have a processor who's job is to persist files back to the disk. This is running as a `Task` while observing a `BlockingCollection<T>` for files to process.

When the task gets cancelled and there are still files which should be saved to the disk, what would be a good practice for doing so?

It would be convenient to let the task right before exiting quickly write the files remaining back to the disk although I'm not sure if this conflicts with the philosophy of cancelling a task (since cancellation should happen as quick as possible).

Another option is having a second procedure after cancelling the task who's job is to write the remaining files to the disk.

Code example:

```
class FileProcessor
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<Stream> input;

    public FileProcessor(BlockingCollection<Stream> input)
    {
        _input = input;
    }

    public Task Run(CancellationToken cancellationToken, 
        BlockingCollection<Stream> input)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
        {
            foreach (Stream stream in 
                        input.GetConsumingEnumerable(cancellationToken))
            {
                WriteToDisk(stream);
            }

            // Should I call WriteRemaining here or should I have
                    // a process running after this task exited which 
                    // will call WriteRemaining
            WriteRemaining();
        });
    }

    public void WriteRemaining()
    {
        foreach (Stream stream in input)    
        {
            WriteToDisk(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

I know this is a bit of an open question, the application/requirements/amount of files to write also play a role but I'm seeking for the general guideline/best practices here.

Comment: I don't think you really want to "Cancel" in this case, I think you just want to stop processing which you could easily accomplish with a simple semaphore on any new start.  To mean "Cancel" implies stop immediately for something else, if you want a safe "Stop" then you can accomplish that outside the cancel stuff potentially.  But I'm not sure if thats a best practice...

Comment: shouldnt the onus of completing rest of writes be on the caller of cancellation ? IMO WriteRemaining should be in the Register method of CancellationToken object

Comment: There's no contractual obligation for Cancel to cause fast termination or to even cause cancellation at all.  If your process does not support cancellation, then you can ignore the Cancel and simply complete successfully.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Cancellation is a cooperative action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364.aspx) when working with the Task Parallel Library, and yes, cancelling is recommended to be a quick operation.

Remember, this is a *cancellation*, not a *cancellation and cleanup*.  If you have extra operations that you need to perform as the result of a cancellation, then those operations should occur *outside of the original task* that was cancelled.

Note that this doesn't stop you from calling [`ContinueWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696.aspx) and performing an operation in a *new* [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) which checks to see if the [`IsCanceled` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.iscanceled.aspx) returns `true` and then performs the cleanup based on that.

The key point here is that you don't want to block the original `Task` that was cancelled, but you are free to start a new `Task` to perform whatever cleanup you need to do as a result of the cancellation.